# Specific formatting to insert generic margin with css inside php file

Tags: php, css, formatting, margins

I have the following code and displayed output on a webpage shown below...

[image: displayed php webpage]

...and wish to create a slight indent in the margin so that the left align is not so severely on the left? The result is generated from two text files, so it is the main code that generates the css

It appears to be this line that generates the left as opposed to centre command;

```
<div class="col-lg-10 text-left">
```

The whole code snippet in question is here:

```
<!-- Main
    ============================================= -->
    <section id="code">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:left;">

            <p></br></br></br></br></p>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-left">
                <p></br></br></br></br></p>

                <?php include 'quiz-sidebar.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 text-left">

            <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
            <p></br></p>

            <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 5px;">
            <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questiontrinket.php"; ?>
            </div>
```

What do I need to add to the existing code to get the margins to be rendered correctly (i.e with an indent for both the intro text (questiontrinket.php) and the questions held in question.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: deleted previous answer since he needs a copy paste solution.

Here goes:

```
<!-- Main
    ============================================= -->
    <section id="code">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="text-align:left;">

            <p></br></br></br></br></p>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 text-left">
                <p></br></br></br></br></p>

                <?php include 'quiz-sidebar.php'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 text-left">

            <h2 class="section-heading" style="color:black;">Test Your Knowledge : <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/title.txt"; ?></h2>
            <p></br></p>

            <div style="border-style: solid; border-radius: 5px; border-width: 5px;">
                <div class="questions" style="display:block; padding-left: 10px;">
                    <style>
                        .questions input[type="radio"]{
                            margin-left: 5px;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php include "content/quiz/". $_GET['quiz'] ."/questiontrinket.php"; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Tried what you've suggested, but it doesn't change the style/output. Not sure where the content of the div would be..

Comment: Hit ctrl+u in the browser and copy-paste it into https://jsfiddle.net/ and give us the link. Much more helpful

Comment: never done that before. Just tried it - but where do I paste all the code. Note, it's a php file, not HTML

Comment: we need to see the source code of the resulting page, that you see in the browser. You posted a printscreen above; go to that page, hit ctrl+u and you'll see the html source code

Comment: yes! that's it. I see the problem. the code is generated poorly without wrapping specific questions. I will edit my answer above

Comment: Thanks so much - but I don't really follow where to add it. It's a PHP page and the questions are generated from a question.txt file (so cannot add any styling or css in there). The command or call to format comes from the php page. What I'd need as an answer, is for you to put your suggested answer into my existing code, so I know where to use it. Thanks in advance